# NodeJS+Socket.io Chat app making fresh connection every time a new message is sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am developing a real-time chat room using socket.io. On pressing the "Send" button, the page reloads and a new connection is made. I know I am missing on the placement of the javascript code.

I followed this tutorial http://javabeginnerstutorial.com/javascript-2/create-simple-chat-application-using-node-js-express-js-socket-io/#comment-4868 but couldn't get the code to work. Tried every possible pattern.

server.js

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var path = require('path');

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 3000));

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
var express = require('express');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname)));
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../ATTEMPT-2', 'index.html'));
});


io.on('connect', function(socket) {

console.log('A new user is connected'); 

    socket.on('chatMessage', function(from, msg) {
        io.emit('chatMessage', from, msg);
    });

    socket.on('notifyUser', function(user) {
        io.emit('notifyUser', user);
    });
});




http.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log('The application is running on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

chat.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var socket = io();

function submitFunction() {

    var from = $('#user').val();
    var message = $('#m').val();

    if (message != '') {

        socket.emit('chatMessage', from, message);
    }

    $('#m').val('');
    return flase;
}


function notifyTyping() {
    var user = $('#user').val();
    socket.emit('notifyUser', user);
}

socket.on('chatMessage', function(from, msg) {
    var me = $('#user').val();
    var color = (from == me) ? 'green' : '#009afd';
    var from = (from == me) ? 'Me' : from;
    $('#messages').append('<li><strong style="color:' + color + '">' + from 
    + '</strong>:' + msg + '</li>');
});


socket.on('notifyUser', function(user) {
    var me = $('#user').val();
    if (user != me) {
        $('#notifyUser').text(user + 'is typing...');
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
        $('#notifyUser').text('');
    }, 10000);
});

// CREATE USERS
var name = makeId();

$('#user').val(name);

socket.emit('chatMessage', 'System', '<strong>' + name + '</strong> has 
joined the conversation!');
});


function makeId() {
    var text = "";
    var possible = 
    "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

     for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*possible.length));
    }
    return text;
}
```

index.html -> putting out only the important part

```
<head>
   <title>Chat App | DB</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">

   <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
   <script src="chat.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="chat">
    <input type="text" class="chat-name" placeholder="Enter your name">
    <div class="chat-messages">
        <ul id="messages"></ul>
        <span id="notifyUser"></span>
    </div>

    <div id="sending-form">
    <form id="form" action="" onsubmit="return submitFunction();">
    <input type="hidden" id="user" value="" />
    <input id="m" autocomplete="off" onkeyup="notifyTyping();" 
    placeholder="Type yor message here.." />
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="send-btn" value="Send">
    </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: looks like your form is submitting. I don't think you need to use a form for this case. Try removing your form tag and when `id="send-btn"` is clicked call `submitFunction()` I would rename that to `sendMessage()` or something better. Your form may be submitting due to a typo `return flase;`

Comment: If you don't understand your code, consider setting breakpoints and stepping through your code one line at a time.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is making a fresh connection every time is because every time you submit the form, your page is refreshing, so with every refresh it is calling `var socket = io();` therefore establishing a new connection with the server. Consider performing an AJAX request every time you want to send the form, or override the default refresh behavior of your form.